# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen Header Text Overlay

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

On the website that I am working on, I have a video as header. But I want to have a text overlay over the video. I know the standard twenty seventeen should have text in the bottom left of the header image, but that changes the name and I want more options -for instance font and color.

http://hitfabryk.nl/beta/

Is there a way that I can use that DIV in the top to add some text as overlay?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @BenLonsdale Nothing so far. The standard Website title and slogan import basically does not give me options enough. And it also changes the website's name itself.

Comment: @Remy Netten Did you work out how to add text over the header image other than the site name and tag line which are both in the bottom left of the header image?